# For this prismatic beam, why is the angle between the original tangent to the tangent of the deflected shape at a given point dw/dx?

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry

[Here is the image in question.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2owm.jpg)

I'm primarily referencing 7.11c.

I feel like I'm missing something conceptually about derivatives.

I understand that the derivative will give us the instantaneous rate of change or the tangent at a point. So in this case change in w with respect to x.

But I fail to see how a derivative can be the angle itself.

Comment: It can't be. However, you can express $dw/dx$ as the tangent of some angle $\phi$. If this angle is sufficiently small (as one often assumes in physics problems) then $dw/dx\approx \phi$.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense to me.